# Receber e enviar valor com NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-service, back-end

Como receber inputs com nodeJS e enviar um valor para um determinado elemento da pagina? Exemplo:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require("http");
http.createServer((req, res)=>{
    fs.readFile('index.html',(err, data)=>{
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    });
    let nome = recebe_nome_do_elemento_yourName_da_pagina_html.
    enviar nome para_elemento_showName+" Seja bem vindo!";
}).listen(8080);
console.log("rodando em http://localhost:8080");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="yourName">
    <div name="showName"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

lembrando que se possível que o valor seja enviado para a mesma pagina de origem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Como receber inputs com nodeJS ? ...

Usando requisição GET:

```
//requisição: http://localhost/entry/?name=Marcelo&peso=70
let url  = require("url");
let params = url.parse(req.url, true);
let name = params.query.name;
let peso = params.query.peso;
//agora voce trata o que tem de tratar com o NODEJS
```

> ...e enviar um valor para um elemento da página ?

Aqui está o exemplo completo:

```
//requisição: http://localhost:8080/replace/?name=Marcelo
const fs   = require("fs");
const http = require("http");
const url  = require("url");
http.createServer((req, res)=>{
    let params = url.parse(req.url, true);
    fs.readFile("index.html", function(err, data){
      let html = data.toString();
      html     = html.replace('<!--NAME-->', params.query.name + " olá !!!");
      res.writeHead(200, { "content-type": "text/html" });
      res.end(html);
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

Este é meu `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--NODEJS vai colocar o nome dentro do comentário-->
    <div><!--NAME--></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

## Se eu fosse você...

-Usaria express, mais fácil de usar rotas.

-Enviaria o nome, neste caso, para o NodeJS e seja lá o que você quer fazer dentro do NodeJS retorne o JSON com a messagem de sucesso e o nome do usuário se quiser. Exemplo:

**1** Envio o ajax para `http://localhost:8080/user/insert/?name=Marcelo`
 **2** Recebo `{bool: true, message: 'Inserido!', data: { name: 'Marcelo' }}`
 **3** Já estou no index.html, agora é só pegar a resposta e inserir o nome do usuário naquela div desejada.

**Não sei se você está querendo fazer Server Side Rendering**.